# Unable to scroll select options in modal dialog (Chrome)

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I have a form within a dialog that has a large number of select option elements. This works fine in IE and FF, but in Chrome, I am unable to scroll through the options. I can select them by selecting an option, then after the options collapse back down, use the arrow keys to go through the list. I am using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 and jQuery 1.9.1. I did attempt it using 1.10.2 as well and it did not fix the problem. My fiddle example uses 1.9.1 because selecting 1.10.2 did not allow be to include jQuery UI 1.9.2. You can even see in fiddle that the framework select input is not scrollable. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4mH8a/19/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Open Modal" onclick="$('#divSelect').dialog('open');" />
</form>

<div id="divSelect" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <select name="lotsofoptions">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
        <option value="5">option 5</option>
        <option value="6">option 6</option>
        <option value="7">option 7</option>
        <option value="8">option 8</option>
        <option value="9">option 9</option>
        <option value="10">option 10</option>
        <option value="11">option 11</option>
        <option value="12">option 12</option>
        <option value="13">option 13</option>
        <option value="14">option 14</option>
        <option value="15">option 15</option>
        <option value="16">option 16</option>
        <option value="17">option 17</option>
        <option value="18">option 18</option>
        <option value="19">option 19</option>
        <option value="20">option 20</option>
        <option value="21">option 21</option>
        <option value="22">option 22</option>
        <option value="23">option 23</option>
        <option value="24">option 24</option>
        <option value="25">option 25</option>
        <option value="26">option 26</option>
        <option value="27">option 27</option>
        <option value="28">option 28</option>
        <option value="29">option 29</option>
        <option value="30">option 30</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Modal dialogs
    $('#divSelect').dialog( {   autoOpen:false,
                                modal: true,
                                title: 'Unable to scroll',
                                open: function (event, ui) { window.setTimeout(function () { 
jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay').unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay'); }, 100); 
                                    }
                        } );
});
```